# Volatile gpu-util is 100% and no progress on PyTorch1.1 after infering lots of images

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, pytorch, nvidia

I deploy a pretrained deep model on NVIDIA V100 GPU. After infering lots of images, I find Volatile GPU-Utils still shows 100%, but no infering is running now. How to fix this problem?

When I type `nvidia-smi`, it shows:

> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | NVIDIA-SMI 384.183      Driver Version: 384.183      CUDA Version: 9.0      |
>   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
>   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
>   |=============+=============+===============|
>   |   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
>   | N/A   43C    P0    51W / 250W |   2530MiB / 32502MiB |    100%      Default |

I have tried **sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1** to enable Persistence Mode. But the problem still remains.